# System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.recv webservice exception

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, exception

Have a client facing web-service which this morning started throwing a very strange exception.

```
Thread was being aborted.    
at System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.recv(IntPtr socketHandle, Byte* pinnedBuffer, Int32 len, SocketFlags socketFlags)     
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, SocketError& errorCode)     
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)     
at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)     
at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)     
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndWriteHeaders(Boolean async)     
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.WriteHeadersCallback(WebExceptionStatus errorStatus, ConnectStream stream, Boolean async)     
at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)     
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndSubmitRequest()     
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()     
at Microsoft.Web.Services2.SoapWebResponse..ctor(SoapWebRequest soapRequest)     
at Microsoft.Web.Services2.SoapWebRequest.GetResponse()     
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)     
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)     
at Microsoft.Web.Services2.WebServicesClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)     
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)     
at MyMethodHere...
```

Gets through all my methods but then when getting the response is falling over.

Anyone seen this exception before? Has me stumped!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have you using Net 2.0 ,that contains this bug.
There the [remedy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetremoting/archive/2006/10/14/whidbey-remoting-accessviolation-problem-maheshwar-jayaraman.aspx):
To get this QFE call Microsoft Product Support Services (http://support.microsoft.com) and ask for the Hotfix for KB number 923028